# Kendo UI dropdown list - different background color to each list item

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-dropdown

How to provide different background colors to each list item (non-selected) in the Kendo UI dropdown list rather than giving a common background color to the whole dropdown?

Answer (score 3):

You should defined a template that sets the appropriate color.

Example:

Define the DataSource as:

```
var colors = [
    "red",
    "green",
    "pink",
    "blue",
    "yellow"
];
```

And a template as:

```
<script id="template" type="text/kendo-script">
    <div style="background-color: #= data #">#= data #</div>
</script>
```

Then your dropdownlist definition should be as:

```
var template = kendo.template($("#template").html())
$("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
    dataSource: colors,
    template : template
});
```

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/MzLrS/

Comment: Using the same jsFiddle, is there a way to make the background color change for the selected item?

Comment: you saved my life. i have a class bg-somecolor
and my item has Color with value somecolor .. I just could do
background-color: "bg-#: Color #"